# How can I pass parameters to a module pattern to override default values [private properties] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was reading this article http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#revealing and was wondering if I can pass parameters to override the private properties.

```
// revealing module pattern
var anchorChange4 = function () {

    // this will be a private property
    var config = {
        colors: [ "#F63", "#CC0", "#CFF" ]
    }

    // this will be a public method
    var init = function () {
        var self = this; // assign reference to current object to "self"

        // get all links on the page
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var size = anchors.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            anchors[i].color = config.colors[i];

            anchors[i].onclick = function () {
                self.changeColor(this, this.color); // this is bound to the anchor object
                return false;
            };
        }
    }

    // this will be a public method
    var changeColor = function (linkObj, newColor) {
        linkObj.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    }

    return {
        // declare which properties and methods are supposed to be public
        init: init,
        changeColor: changeColor
    }
}();

anchorChange4.init();
```

I'm trying to change the values of the Array colors, like passing different colors as parameters. I hope I'm making some sense.

Comment: You can make `init` accept a `config` parameter and extend the private one with this one.

Comment: @felix You mean pass parameters to the init function and change the config using them?

Comment: @Felix Could you please show how you would go about extending the private values with the parameters passed?

Comment: You cannot overwrite private properties, that is why they are private. You should use a public method that sets the properties like `var setColors=function(colors){this.config.colors=colors;}` and use `obj.setColors([ "#F63", "#CC0", "#CFF" ]);`

Comment: @manraj82: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: :) isn't that the whole point of private variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `init` accept a configuration parameter and extend the private configuration with this one:

```
var init = function (options) {
    // copy properties of `options` to `config`. Will overwrite existing ones.
    for(var prop in options) {
        if(options.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            config[prop] = options[prop];
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you can pass an object to `init`:

```
anchorChange4.init({
    colors: ['#FFF', '#000']
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i didnt quite get the if(options.hasOwnProperty(prop)) bit,would you please ne abl to explain that? And i was reading this article as well http://www.engfers.com/code/javascript-module-pattern/ ,I know they are both returning anonymous objects,but its different the way they are declared.Could you please tell me the difference?

Comment: @manraj82: Regarding `hasOwnProperty`, have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). It is basically a safe guard to not copy inherited properties. The difference is that in your code, you only have one instance of your "module" whereas in the other code you can have multiple ones. If you'd change your code to `var anchorChange4 = function () {...};` (without parenthesis at the end) you could do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by doing the following in your return object:-

```
return {
        Init: function(params) { init(params); },
        Start: start,
        Stop: stop,
        Pause: pause
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did something similar for a plugin i am working on, with a slightly different way and checking passed arguments for objects:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';


    var MyPlugin = function(){

        var options = null;

        var defaults = {
          className: 'fade-and-drop',
          closeButton: true
        }


        var init = function() {

            // First Extend Default Options
            if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
                options = _extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
            }

            _somePrivate();
        }

        var _somePrivate = function(){
           //access option as option.parameter
        }

        // Extend defaults with user options
         var _extendDefaults = function(source, properties) {
            var property;
            for (property in properties) {
              if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                source[property] = properties[property];
              }
            }
            return source; // to set options var
          }


        return {
            init:init,
        }

    }();

    MyPlugin.init({
        selector:'input__field--select',
        maxWidth: 750
    });

}());
```